# How to handle nested delimiter character in fields in CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm unable to create a mapping / configuration for the following sample data:

`W001;MFS;4262;EMFS;{MFS;W001;;};109;11;"A";["TEID","Int "]`

Which should result in something like:

1. W001
2. MFS
3. 4262
4. EMFS
5. {MFS;W001;;}
6. 109
7. ...

Every time I try, the value for field 5 is `{MFS`, because the nested semicolon is recognized as the delimiter character.
Also setting the quote character is not an option, in that case.

Or an input like this:

`MFS1;W001;8;STSO;TL1B;;[{"ON00000008";;DP;"LC00420017";{SO;1;;;;;;};[]}]`

Where `[{"ON00000008";;DP;"LC00420017";{SO;1;;;;;;};[]}]` should be treated as a single field.

Is this possible at all with CsvHelper or are there other recommendations?

Comment: delimiter indicates the end of the field
you should escape the fields using double quotes. otherwise don't use csvhelper as it's not valid csv file. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

Comment: What language are you using?  [tag:c#]?  Can you show what you tried that did not work?

Comment: If you are using [tag:.net] or [tag:.net-core] with the [`CsvHelper`](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) library, then I don't think you can do what you need.  `CsvConfiguration` has a single [`Delimiter`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L46) property, but what you would need are distinct `StartDelimiter = '{'` and `EndDelimiter = '}'` properties.  Using different characters for start and end delimiters is not implemented by `CsvHelper` as far as I know.

Comment: I‘m using C#.

Thank you, I think you are both correct and this simply isn’t valid CSV and possible to do with CsvHelper. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

The comment from Boris Maslennikov answers the question.
My data is invalid CSV and CsvHelper is not the right tool to parse this kind of data.
Thank you Boris Maslennikov and dbc for your comments and help!